# Ao filtrar os indices e acessar o mesmo indice em outro vetor não aparece nada na tela. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var codigo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var veiculos = [1000,2000,10000,5000,12958,502,985,125,967,1500]
var acidentes = [500,123,1500,350,600,25,15,20,129,159]

var indices = []

var teste = veiculos.filter((carro, index) => { //retorna o indice de veiculos menor que 2000
    if (carro < 2000) {
     indices.push(index)
    }

  })

res.innerHTML += `<p>indices do vetor veiculos com carros menor que 2000: ${indices}, </p>`// mostra todos os indices

var novoAci = []

var teste2 = acidentes.filter((acidente, index) => { //retorna o os acidentes se o index for igual ao indice
  if (index == indices) {
   novoAci.push(acidente)
  }

})


res.innerHTML += `<p>Acidentes com veículos menor que 2000: ${novoAci}, </p>`// não mostra nada na tela
```

Comment: ele não está retornando pq você está comparando um array com um numero em teste2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema se deve por conta da sua comparação `index == indices` como indices é um array e index um int, ele retorna false e não da o push no seu array `novoAci`

para corrigir isso você pode fazer um `map` em `indices` e comparar o valor em `indices` com o valor de `index`

```js
var codigo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var veiculos = [1000,2000,10000,5000,12958,502,985,125,967,1500]
var acidentes = [500,123,1500,350,600,25,15,20,129,159]

var indices = []

var teste = veiculos.filter((carro, index) => { //retorna o indice de veiculos menor que 2000
    if (carro < 2000) {
     indices.push(index)
    }

  })

var novoAci = []

var teste2 = acidentes.filter((acidente, index) => { //retorna o os acidentes se o index for igual ao indice
indices.map((i)=>{
 if (index == i) {
     novoAci.push(acidente)
   }
})
  

})

console.log(novoAci)
```

Você tambem poderia obter o mesmo resultado sem a necessidade de fazer um `filter`, fazendo um `map` em `indices` e fazendo o `push` em `novoAci` pegando o valor de `acidentes` dessa forma:

```
indices.map(i=>{ 
    novoAci.push(acidentes[i])
 })
```